# Screen temporarily freezes when watching a video

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, video

Whenever I'm watching a video the screen freezes for about 1 second and then goes back to normal, this happens every 30 seconds or so. Usually happens when showing a video on the screen (YouTube, Facebook, Twitch, VLC, Videos), while any other activities work ​normally. Are there any tips or tricks for fixing this? **Note**: I have dual boot on my machine (Ubuntu,Windows 10) and this issue doesn't happen on Windows.

- **Ubuntu version**: 18.04.5 LTS (Desktop Environment: GNOME). **OS**: 64 bit. **GNOME**: 3.28.2
- **Graphics card**: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2. **Driver Version**: 440.33.01. **CUDA Version**: 10.2. **prime-select**: nvidia
- **Processor**: Intel® Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8
- `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            19G        5,6G        4,7G        312M        9,1G         13G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G
```

Comment: It might be a problem of the video player you are using. Did you try the latest `vlc` for comparison?

Comment: @HuHa It's not limited to video players. I've updated the question, therefore Youtube, Twitch, and Facebook media suffer the same way as local files played in video players.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @waltinator I've tried only having Chrome opened while watching a YouTube video, but the freezing still happens. Now regarding the swap space, currently it has 2GB while my computer has 20GB of available RAM, is it needed for me to increase?

Comment: If it doesn't work with 20 GB RAM + 2 GB swap, it won't work at all. ;-) But you can check with `free -h` how much RAM are available.

Comment: Since you mentioned CUDA: Are you running any processes that use CUDA? Like a Bitcoin miner or anything similar?

Comment: So we see lots of RAM that isn't even used for filesystem buffers; I don't think RAM / swap is an issue here.

Comment: @HuHa Not that I know of, usually my CUDA is only used to train and infer Deep Learning models, but it's not used all the time.

Comment: @HuHa Regarding this issue you sent me, I have dual boot on my machine, but on Windows 10 this issue doesn't happen. Also, I'm working with a dual monitor setup, however, this issue was present even with one monitor. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by fixing the CUDA installation on my machine.

**Note**: some PPAs related to this toolkit had to be removed from my OS repository list (e.g., TensorRT), since they were conflicting with the overall process.

Answer (score 0):

I also have 18.04 LTS with NVidia (GeForce GTX 1050 Ti), and I am using nvidia-driver-465. It might be worthwhile to upgrade to that driver.

If you need CUDA, there is nvidia-driver-460-server (I didn't try that one).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've tested updating the Nvidia driver (v. 460), but, unfortunately, the freezing didn't stop and a CUDA incompatibility was raised, therefore I switched back to the previous driver (v. 440).